# Including intercept terms in piecewise linear programming

Tags: python, optimization, piecewise-linear, linear-programming

I am hoping to get some help in understanding whether the intercept terms are required in the objective function for piecewise linear programming (using the below code).

```
import pulp as pl

# Pieces
pieces = [1, 2]

# Problem 
prob = pl.LpProblem('Example', pl.LpMaximize)

# Decision Vars
x_vars = pl.LpVariable.dict('x', pieces, 0, None, pl.LpInteger)
y_vars = pl.LpVariable.dict('y', pieces, 0, None, pl.LpInteger)

# Objective
prob += (-500+10*x_vars[1]) + (150+9*x_vars[2]) + (2+9.1*y_vars[1]) + (4+6*y_vars[2])

# Constraints
prob += pl.lpSum(x_vars[i] for i in pieces) + pl.lpSum(y_vars[i] for i in pieces) <= 1100

prob += x_vars[1] <= 700
prob += x_vars[2] <= 700
prob += y_vars[1] <= 400
prob += y_vars[2] <= 400

# Solve
prob.solve()

# Results
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", pl.value(v))
```

The terms included in the objective function are the piecewise intercepts and coefficients obtained from univariate piecewise regression models. For example, the linear regression model for `x` is `yhat=-500+10*x` for the first piece, and `yhat=150+9*x` for the second piece. Likewise, for `y` we have `yhat=2+9.1*x` and `yhat=4+6*x` for the first and second pieces, respectively.

If I remove and/or change any of the intercept values, I arrive at the same solution. I would have thought that each intercept is required to produce the estimates for the objective function. I am nonetheless new to linear programming and wondering if the intercept terms are not required/accounted for this purpose?

Comment: The question doesn't seem related to statistics...

Comment: @utobi "If I remove and/or change any of the intercept values, I arrive at the same solution." This phrase reveals that this question lies at the nexus of optimization and approximation, which I like to think is related to statistics.